# Sourcing GIS map and shapefile of Sudan

Tags: shapefile, data

I have no prior knowledge with GIS.

I am looking to source a GIS map of Sudan (North Sudan) after the succession (2010) projecting the states of Sudan.

I also need to get a shapefile of Sudan.

I have done some research but would like to be certain I am using the correct files.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the shapefiles for Sudan [here](https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata). I just tried it out myself. The download will give you four shapefiles, each divided by region/sub-region.